# Divide $n$ people into $k$ teams with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many ways are there to divide $n$ people into $k$ distinct teams with the following restrictions:

1. Each person has to be in at least $1$ team
2. Each person can enlist to at most $2$ teams
3. Each team has to have at least $1$ person

It is inclusion-exclusion but I am not exactly sure how, I tried several things but failed.

My best attemp was:

Let $A_1$ be the number of ways to divide the people into all the teams beside team $1$
my attemp was I will first pick the number of people that are in $2$ teams $\binom{n}{j}$ and divide $n+j$ people to $k-1$ teams so I have $\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}{(k-1)^{n+j}}$ and i think i also need to divide by $2^{j}$ but both ways doesnt add up when i try the formola for some numbers.

Comment: Are the teams themselves somehow distinct (e.g. is there one swimming team, one football team, etc.), or is all that matters who's on team with who?

Comment: Are there any restrictions from the team's perspective?  Must each team have at least one person on it or can some teams be empty?

Comment: edited the post with answer for both of you.they are distinct  and all teams needs to have at least 1 person.
thanks for the clear up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you counting strategy is flawed; you consider choosing the $j$ people who get two teams, forming "duplicates" of those people to make $n+j$ people, and then arbitrarily assigning the $n+j$ people to $k-1$ teams. (Side note: Why is it $k-1$? Shouldn't it be $k$?) However, this allows two duplicate people to be assigned to the same team, which is double counting.

Ignoring condition $3$, then number of ways to assign each person to $1$ or $2$ teams is
$$
\bigg(k+\binom{k}2\bigg)^n,
$$
because for each of the $n$ people, you can either assign them to $1$ team in $k$ ways, or $2$ teams in $\binom{k}2$ ways. To account for condition $3$, you need to subtract the "bad" arrangements where some team is empty. This is where the principle of inclusion exclusion comes in. For each of the $k$ teams, $T$, we subtract the arrangements where team $T$ has no members. The result is
$$
\bigg(k+\binom{k}2\bigg)^n-k\times \bigg((k-1)+\binom{k-1}2\bigg)^n
$$
However, this doubly subtracts the situations where *two* teams were empty, so to correct he above, we must add back in the number of situations where two particular teams are empty, for each of the $\binom{k}2$ pairs of teams. Continuing as you usually do when using the principle of inclusion-exclusion, you then add the situations with three empty teams, subtract the situations with $4$ empty teams, and so on.

I leaver it to you to fill in the rest of the details...

Comment: I think i understand, so i should get : $\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{i}\binom{k}{i}((k-i)+\binom{k-i}{2})^{n}$
and my bad attemp that you side noted was trying to find $A_1$ which is what you wrote about T, but i didn't do it correctly. thank you!

Comment: @RoiHezkiyahu Ohh, I see now, sorry for not recognizing your progress. Your trick was a good idea, it just happened to not quite work.